# How can I find what is preventing a Windows computer from shutting down remotely?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, event-log

We have Windows Server 2008 Service Pack 2 machines that we reboot from a Linux server using `net rpc shutdown -f -r -I {ip_address} -U user%password`. Usually this works fine. However, sometimes the machine gets the request and does not shutdown. I can't find anything in the logs indicating why the shutdown was cancelled. Here is the event log:

```
The process wininit.exe (10.18.28.223) has initiated the restart of computer server on behalf of user server\user for the following reason: Legacy API shutdown
 Reason Code: 0x80070000
 Shutdown Type: restart
 Comment: This machine will be shutdown shortly
```

Comment: That event from the log is not helpful - this is just a confirmation that the command was received. is there any other entry in the event log(s) -look in the system and app log that would show an app has prevented a restart?

Comment: @TomEus That is literally my question.There is nothing else in the System, Application, or Security logs around that time that looks interesting. I'm asking where else should I look.

Comment: Does it matter if there is any user logged in at the console or RDP at all? In other words, if there are no users logged in to the system (including suspended or disconnected) users, does it behave differently than when they are?

Comment: Does this only happen if you initiate the shutdown from the Linux box? Do you get different results if you initiate the shutdown from a Windows machine?

Comment: @Twisty yes it can shut down from the machine fine

Comment: @Appleoddity I forwarded your question to the users the people who saw this happen in multiple machines. I did notice that the Windows function that requires a comment for shutdown is not enabled.

Comment: @kagronick Sorry, I wasn't clear. I was asking if you can initiate a *remote* shutdown from one Windows box to the other with different results than from the Linux box.